# Count multiple letters in different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I'm looking for a formula that can count different letters included in different cells.

Example:

- Cell A2 includes a letter "S"
- Cell A3 includes a letter "F"
- Cell A4 includes a letter "N"
- Cell A5 includes a letter "A" (I don't want this letter to be counted.)

It should count in total "3" and I'd like S,F,N to be highlighted in green color which I'm not sure how to do.

I can't use the `COUNTA` formula here because I want to only count some specific letters I choose myself, not every letter.

Hope somebody got a solution!

Comment: Only S in A2 or there is a text contain S in A2?

Comment: Only single specific letters in different cells :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of functions for counting if you read the Excel manual. In this case use [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34)

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A5, "S") + COUNTIF(A2:A5, "F") + COUNTIF(A2:A5, "N")
```

For highlighting simply write the condition as

```
=OR(A2="S", A2="F", A2="N")
```